# Erro no arquivo de saida

Tags: c, funções, arquivo

Em um exercício, preciso ler um arquivo de entrada da seguinte maneira:

```
# add # Jabuticaba # Fruto de jabuticabeira. Jabuticabeira.
# add # Vacilar # Não estar firme. Cambalear. Oscilar. Tremer.
# add # Jacapa # Pássaro brasileiro escuro, de bico branco.
# search # Jacapa
# search # Jabuticaba
# search # Jacapa
# search # Vacilar
# sort
```

Onde cada conteúdo está entre `#`. Primeiro, tem-se a operação a ser feita: `Add` (adicionar), `search` (pesquisar) e `sort` (ordenar). O segundo conteúdo é a palavra e o terceiro conteúdo o seu respectivo significado. Por exemplo, para a primeira linha, o que deve ser feito é adicionar a palavra Jabuticaba à uma lista de palavras que será ordenada alfabeticamente ao final do arquivo. Lembrando que deve-se ter o significado da palavra também. Para as informações, eu criei a seguinte struct

```
typedef struct
{
    char palavra[MAX];
    char sign[MAX];
}Item;
```

A struct tem dois campos: Um array para armazenar a própria palavra e um array para armazenar o seu significado.

Para ler o arquivo e saber qual operação eu devo realizar, eu utilizei a função `strtok` para armazenar apenas o conteúdo da string que está entre `#`. Segue abaixo a função para a leitura do arquivo:

```
void LeEntrada(FILE *entrada, FILE *saida, FILE *dicionario, ArvBin *raiz, Item info)
{
    char linha[MAX];
    int i;
    char marc[3] = "#";

    if(entrada == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) //Faz os passos linha por linha
    {
        fgets(linha, MAX, entrada);
        char *token;

        token = strtok(linha, marc);

        if(strcmp(token, " add ") == 0)
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, marc);
            strcpy(info.palavra, token);
            Insere_Arvore(raiz, info);

            token = strtok(NULL, marc);
            strcpy(info.sign, token);
            fprintf(saida, "add%s\n", info.palavra);
        }

        else if(strcmp(token, " search ") == 0)
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, marc);
            strcpy(info.palavra, token);
            printf("%s\n", info.palavra);
            printf("%s\n", info.sign);
            Consulta_Arvore(raiz, info);
            fprintf(saida, "search%s #%s\n", info.palavra, info.sign);
        }
    }
}
```

Há três arquivos como parâmetro para a função: O arquivo de `entrada`, usado para a leitura, um arquivo de `saida` e um arquivo `dicionario`. O arquivo `saida` será usado para escrever um tipo de log nela, ou seja, para cada operação, eu escrevo nesse arquivo o que foi feito. Por exemplo:

```
add Jabuticaba
add Vacilar
add Jacapa
search Jacapa # Pássaro brasileiro escuro, de bico branco.
search Jabuticaba # Fruto de jabuticabeira. Jabuticabeira.
search Jacapa # Pássaro brasileiro escuro, de bico branco.
```

Porém, testando com a função que fiz, para o arquivo de `saida`, eu tenho o seguinte resultado:

```
add Jabuticaba 
add Vacilar 
add Jacapa 
search Jacapa
 # Pássaro brasileiro escuro, de bico branco.

search Jabuticaba
 # Pássaro brasileiro escuro, de bico branco.

search Jacapa
 # Pássaro brasileiro escuro, de bico branco.

search Vacilar
 # Pássaro brasileiro escuro, de bico branco.
```

Não sei por quê razão após o primeiro "search", há um salto de linha `\n` e por quê o conteúdo do significado da palavra é repetido. O que notei é que ele repete o significado da última palavra adicionada que, no caso, é Jacapa.

Gostaria de saber qual a razão desse comportamento e se há alguma forma de resolver.

Comment: Você já tentou imprimir todo o conteúdo o do array de significados ? Se o array mostrar sempre o mesmo conteúdo é porque na hora de gravar o programa percorre o array e sobre escreve o que ta la, se o programa mostrar para você conteúdo certo é porque na hora de puxar a informação, ele esta pegando a última salvo, se possível poste o resultado da impressão do array